# Calculate quantity of tickets based on how many reserved using sub queries

Tags: mysql, subquery, group-by, count

I'm designing a database that will hold ticketing information. The 3 tables I use to track ticketing are

`tbl_ticket_type` to the types of events an event can have

`tbl_ticket_count` to keep track of how many tickets of a particular type should be sold for an event

`tbl_tickets` to keep track of the actual tickets purchased by users.

I'm trying to design a query that will calculate the number of ticket types left for a particular event and return the result in groups of the types and number left. I tried the following SQL statement but to no avail, how can I fix SQL to return types of tickets and quantities left? DB inset attached

```
SELECT tt.ticket_type,COUNT(tt.ticket_type) 
FROM tbl_tickets t 
INNER JOIN tbl_ticket_count tc ON t.ticket_count_id=tc.ticket_count_id 
INNER JOIN tbl_ticket_type tt 
ON     tc.ticket_type_id = tt.ticket_type_id 
WHERE ticket_count_id IN (SELECT tc.ticket_count_id FROM tbl_ticket_count WHERE event_id=15) 
GROUP BY tt.ticket_type
```

Script to recreate the three tables:

**tbl_tickets**

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_tickets` (
  `ticket_id` int(11) NOT NULL ,
  `ticket_count_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0' ,
  `userid` int(11) DEFAULT '0' ,
  `provider_id` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `pay_status` enum('reserved','paid','pending','') DEFAULT 'reserved' ,
  `reference` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'if e-payment, what the reference for the payment',
  `event_status` enum('pending','checked','','') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending' ,
  `date_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;

ALTER TABLE `tbl_tickets`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ticket_id`),
  ADD KEY `ticket_count_id` (`ticket_count_id`),
  ADD KEY `user_id` (`userid`),
  ADD KEY `provider_id` (`provider_id`);
ALTER TABLE `tbl_tickets`
ADD CONSTRAINT `tbl_tickets_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`provider_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_provider` (`provider_id`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `tbl_tickets_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ticket_count_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_ticket_count` (`ticket_count_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
INSERT INTO `tbl_tickets` (`ticket_id`, `ticket_count_id`, `userid`, `provider_id`, `pay_status`, `reference`, `event_status`, `date_time`) VALUES
(3, 1, 2, 1, 'reserved', NULL, 'pending', '2017-11-04 15:14:15'),
(4, 1, 6, 1, 'pending', NULL, 'pending', '2017-11-04 15:14:15'),
(5, 10, 6, 1, 'reserved', NULL, 'pending', '2017-11-04 16:32:35'),
(6, 10, 2, 1, 'reserved', NULL, 'pending', '2017-11-04 16:32:35');
```

**tbl_ticket_count**

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_ticket_count` (
  `ticket_count_id` int(11) NOT NULL ,
  `ticket_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0' ,
  `event_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0' ,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT '0' ,
  `price` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT '0' ,
  `date_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `tbl_ticket_count`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ticket_count_id`),
  ADD KEY `ticket_type_id` (`ticket_type_id`),
  ADD KEY `event_id` (`event_id`);
ALTER TABLE `tbl_ticket_count`
ADD CONSTRAINT `tbl_ticket_count_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ticket_type_id`)     REFERENCES `tbl_ticket_type` (`ticket_type_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
ADD CONSTRAINT `tbl_ticket_count_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_events_new` (`event_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
INSERT INTO `tbl_ticket_count` (`ticket_count_id`, `ticket_type_id`, `event_id`, `quantity`, `price`, `date_time`) VALUES
(1, 1, 3, 10, 15000, '2017-11-04 14:45:02'),
(2, 2, 3, 10, 25000, '2017-11-04 14:45:02'),
(3, 1, 9, 10, 15000, '2017-11-04 14:45:39'),
(4, 2, 9, 10, 25000, '2017-11-04 14:45:51'),
(5, 1, 4, 100, 2000, '2017-11-04 14:47:13'),
(6, 1, 5, 50, 4000, '2017-11-04 14:48:17'),
(7, 5, 10, 15, 100000, '2017-11-04 14:48:17'),
(8, 1, 8, 50, 0, '2017-11-04 14:48:48'),
(9, 7, 15, 10, 3000, '2017-11-04 16:31:47'),
(10, 1, 15, 20, 7500, '2017-11-04 16:31:47');
```

**tbl_ticket_type**

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_ticket_type` (
  `ticket_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'stores unique identification for the ticket type',
  `ticket_type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'type of ticket ',
  `description` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'description of that ticket type_category',
  `date_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'datetime the type_category was added'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `tbl_ticket_type`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ticket_type_id`);
INSERT INTO `tbl_ticket_type` (`ticket_type_id`, `ticket_type`, `description`, `date_time`) VALUES
(1, 'Standard', 'These are standard entry tickets that will permit one person into an event venue', '2017-11-04 14:42:41'),
(2, 'VIP', 'These are VIP tickets with VIP access to an event venue', '2017-11-04 14:42:41'),
(3, 'VIPP', 'VIPP tickets to access the VVIP sections of an event venue', '2017-11-04 14:43:32'),
(4, 'Family', 'Tickets to permit a family of a pre determined number by the organisers', '2017-11-04 14:43:32'),
(5, 'Team', 'Team ticket to some events e.g. sporting tournaments', '2017-11-04 14:44:04'),
(6, 'Couples', 'Admits two (2) people into an event venue', '2017-11-04 15:06:00'),
(7, 'Children', 'Tickets aimed at children', '2017-11-04 16:31:00');
```

Comment: Images are a [bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Please delete the image and post the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE blah\G` - help us to help you!

Comment: removed the image and added sql statement instead, just having problems with the formatting @Vérace

Comment: Good - now we're getting somewhere! Can you also put in the FK relationships between the tables? Some sample data and your desired result would be really good!

Comment: added the foreign key constraints and sample data @Vérace

Comment: You may have your answer below - could you in future take the time to actually test the code you post on a service like db-fiddle - or, better still, post the link here to an already working schema? It means a less cluttered post and it's more likely to be read/answered! Help us to help you! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the following queries will help you to find the correct answer (MySQL 5.7).  Assumptions: we need the amount of sold and unsold tickets.  Each row in the tbl_tickets represents ONE sold ticket.  Using a LEFT JOIN, we include "unsold" tickets:

```
select 
  tc.ticket_count_id  TC_ID
, t.ticket_count_id   T_TC_ID
, tc.ticket_type_id   CATEGORY
, tc.event_id         EVENT
, tc.quantity
, count(t.ticket_count_id)  SOLD
, tc.quantity - count(t.ticket_count_id) TICKETS_LEFT
from tbl_ticket_count tc
  left join tbl_tickets t on tc.ticket_count_id = t.ticket_count_id 
group by tc.ticket_count_id
having tc.event_id = 15 ;

-- result
+-------+---------+----------+-------+----------+------+--------------+
| TC_ID | T_TC_ID | CATEGORY | EVENT | quantity | SOLD | TICKETS_LEFT |
+-------+---------+----------+-------+----------+------+--------------+
|     9 |    NULL |        7 |    15 |       10 |    0 |           10 |
|    10 |      10 |        1 |    15 |       20 |    2 |           18 |
+-------+---------+----------+-------+----------+------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If that looks correct to you, join the third table, and adjust the columns of the SELECT clause.

```
select 
  tc.event_id EVENT
, tc.quantity - count(t.ticket_count_id) TICKETS_LEFT
, tt.ticket_type
from tbl_ticket_count tc
  left join tbl_tickets t on tc.ticket_count_id = t.ticket_count_id 
  join tbl_ticket_type tt on tc.ticket_type_id = tt.ticket_type_id
group by tc.ticket_count_id
having tc.event_id = 15 ;

-- result
+-------+--------------+-------------+
| EVENT | TICKETS_LEFT | ticket_type |
+-------+--------------+-------------+
|    15 |           10 | Children    |
|    15 |           18 | Standard    |
+-------+--------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

[Dbfiddle here.](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=18c7e2cf21567ab851185a98aaffa8cf)

*NOTE: The DDL code needed some minor changes for the test setup to work.

E.g. tbl_tickets: duplicated value '' in ENUM.  Some FKs have REFERENCES that fail e.g. tbl_tickets_ibfk_1.*

Comment: wanted to add a condition where only tickets with a certain pay_status are chosen. where can I add that condition? @stefan

Comment: @Manny265: last query - change the GROUP BY and HAVING clauses to:  group by tc.ticket_count_id, t.pay_status
having tc.event_id = 15 and t.pay_status = 'reserved'; ( see dbfiddle @ http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=bd7026f4f51c00bcfe2435ec5e659642 )